# Event handling for dynamically generated controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt

I am working on a module where I am basically generating all the controls on the page dynamically using XSLT.  They are being rendered and added to the mark up right. Here the problem is that I want to write event handling for this dynamically generated controls and I am not sure how to achieve that because in perfect development environment, we normally double click on our control on aspx page and .NET creates a related event for you in the back on the aspx.cs page.

Any ideas?

Comment: The hacker approach:  View the automatically generated code file and copy what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a method with the appropriate handler and wire it up to your dynamically created controls when you create them.

i.e.

```
protected void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

when you create your controls

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
    lb.ID = "lbexample";
    lb.Click += MyHandler;
Page.Form.Controls.Add(lb);
```

But it's very important that on your postback, you rebuild these controls as they were or the event won't fire. You'll need to recreate the controls first so that the event can be raised, so any data that you'll need to create the controls will have to be available on the post back using whatever state mechanism you're comfortable with.

Comment: I think we are looking at something like Delegates here. That's good. Actually, that is what I would like to consider as my second option because it is still server side. I came across something really cool on the client side. JQuery has this great functionality:http://api.jquery.com/click/. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically-added controls generally do not survive postback.

No amount of double-clicking, or even typing the expected names of the controls with _selectedIndexChanged is going to get you what you want.

*This is ASSUMING (please let us know if I'm right or wrong) that you are adding HTML controls, not ASP.NET controls dynamically.*

Comment: Anything possible from Client side that you can think of? something using JQuery or Javascript?

Comment: -1: Dynamically generated controls survive postback perfectly well if you generate them in Page Init.

Comment: Excellent point that didn't cross my mind. If you can update your answer to reflect this possibility, I can reverse the -1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute client-side events, you can specify the name of the method to fire (or the code itself) by adding the appropriate attribute.

For example, if you want to fire `myCheckBox_OnClick` when the user clicks your dynamically generated checkbox, you can do the following:

```
myDynamicallyGeneratedControl.Attributes.Add("onclick", "myCheckBox_OnClick");
```

You could also generate the javascript code that is to be executed and add it to the page through the page's `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` method.

Comment: what would be the Type of "myDynamicallyGeneratedControl"?

Comment: My response assumes that you are generating ASP.Net controls. In my answer, the control would be of type System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox.